# Medically speaking, when a doctor

Tags: punctuation

How can I write this sentence using other punctuations?

▪ Medically speaking, when a doctor vets you — or an animal — medical care is given.

Comment: What are you trying to say? The sentence doesn’t make sense, regardless of the punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pair of commas, or you can use round brackets "()"

You could also remove the dashes to make "you or an animal" the object of the word "vets".

You have to use a comma after "speaking".  Nothing else works.

Overall this looks like a punning sentence. Is it a joke based on "doctor/vet"?

And "punctuation" is a non-count noun (usually) so don't say "punctuations".